# Unable to load images in content script injected pages

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, datatables

I am using the dataTable plugin in a chrome extension to beautify some of the table. I am using the zero configuration in initializing the datatable. The only problem I am facing is to load the images. None of the images are displaying in the formatted table, also I am getting the error in the console saying : `https://mydomain.salesforce.com/images/sort_asc.png 404 (Not Found).`

I have saved the images in the extension folder `(/images/image.png)` and also I have added all the links to images in the `web_accessible_resources` in manifest.json file. Not sure how to get around this issue.

EDIT:

AS you already know the datatable css files refer to the images using path ('/images/imageName.png'). Now when I inject datatable's js and css files, these path will actually become https://mydomain.salesforce.com/image/imageName.png, but since in there is no image in the server an error is shown in the console.

Somehow I want to be able to show these images in the browser from the extensions image folder.

please advise!

Comment: try to  make  image path directly in the browser in address bar

Comment: @rajeshkakawat: I am sorry, I didn't understand your comment.

Comment: image path is build to reference of your css file, so kindly give your css path where you are using image

Answer (score 0):

There is a chrome api to get the path of a web accesible resource. Use that.
chrome.extension.getURL(relativePath)